# Не получается правильно разделить строку методом split

Tags: java, массивы, строки, scanner, split

В строку `numbers` я должен вводить строку чисел через пробел, а затем считать оттуда отдельные числа и сложить их.

Моя реализация, видимо, прерывается после одного пробела в строке или что-то вроде того. Хотелось бы узнать, в чём дело.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter first number: ");
    int start = in.nextInt();
    int result = start;
    int num = 0;
    System.out.println("enter other numbers: ");
    String numbers = in.next();
    String [] arrayOfValues = numbers.split(" ");
    for(int i = 0; i <= arrayOfValues.length; i++){
        num = Integer.parseInt(arrayOfValues[i]);
        result = result + num;
        System.out.println(arrayOfValues[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

}

Comment: какие строки вы вводите?

Comment: множество чисел через пробел, пример: 66 1069 367 1208 786 1272 1063 27 1112 1081 752 1253 169

Comment: после `start = in.nextIint()` просто вставьте `in.nextLine()` без всяких присваиваний.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `nextLine()`, эта конструкция считывает всю строку целиком включая пробелы.

```
String numbers = in.nextLine();
```

Comment: Изначально так и писал, Но мне не дает ввести эту строку - просто проскакивает эту строчку кода как бы.

Comment: @МаркПикановский, это потому что вы считали число, но не дочитали до конца строки. Поэтому следующий вызов `in.nextLine()` просто проглотит окончание той строки, в которой было число (всякие там whitespace с символом перевода строки)

Comment: @МаркПикановский Да, `nextLine()` считывает всю строку и  блокирует ввод, поэтому вам надо что-то ввести прежде чем вы будете пользоваться этой конструкцией. Есть еще вариант использовать `next()` в цикле, но тогда вам надо определить количество элементов в строке.

Comment: [Что означает если ответ "принят"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)